# Is GeoPlanet dead?

Tags: data, api, administrative-boundaries, geoplanet

I'd like to start a side project that will rely heavily on the relationship between places, and GeoPlanet does this wonderfully. However, the latest version I can find of the data [GeoPlanet Data v7.10.0](https://archive.org/details/geoplanet_data_7.10.0.zip), is from 2012-06-01. The [Yahoo GeoPlanet Docs](https://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/) are still available, and the [Yahoo GeoPlanet Data Download Page](https://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/data/) still says that they're working on a better way to surface the data, but there's no sign of an update, and [various sources found via Google News Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=geoplanet&tbm=nws) state that Yahoo would kill the service last year.

This is confusing and discouraging. It doesn't feel safe to use their API or the data at the moment, given it's likely end-of-life and the API data is, without evidence to the contrary, no longer being updated. Is there any evidence otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [Yahoo announces plans to kill off Maps, Pipes, GeoPlanet and PlaceSpotter APIs, and some regional sites](http://venturebeat.com/2015/06/04/yahoo-announces-plans-to-kill-maps-pipes-geoplanet-and-placespotter-apis-and-market-specific-properties/)

> Speaking of developers, Yahoo is killing off two APIs in Q3: GeoPlanet and PlaceSpotter. Yahoo said this is part of standardizing and consolidating its offerings, as the functionality is already in Yahoo Query Language (YQL) for non-commercial usage and BOSS Geo Services for commercial usage.

To me killing off the API means that it will no longer be actively developed, and will eventually be withdrawn; having the docs still available, and no version since v7.10.0 is consistent with this killing off process, and not really `confusing`.

If you had an app that used the API already, now would probably be the time to consider moving to a different API.  It probably isn't the best time to start a new application using the API.

The announcement though suggests that the functionality provided by the GeoPlanet API is also available using Yahoo Query Language (YQL), so you should probably look at using this to access the data.