# Is there an active equivalent to Yahoo GeoPlanet available for commercial use?

Tags: data, api, administrative-boundaries, geoplanet

It looks like GeoPlanet is dead ([Is GeoPlanet dead?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198047/is-geoplanet-dead)).

Is there a suitable alternative that covers Parents (preferably Ancestors) and Neighbours? If there's a name for this type of data, that'd be helpful.

Spatial data would be a plus, but I can get by without it for now.

This project may come to nothing, but in case I am ever able to charge for the service I need to make sure I don't shoot myself in the foot with a restrictive licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to take a look on Mapzen [Who's On First](https://whosonfirst.mapzen.com/) gazeteer project. Not sure if that's what you want but looks like the closest thing to GeoPlanet out there.

Comment: That looks very promising. Seems Mapzen Search is powered by Who's On First, and Who's On First includes all the data from GeoPlanet. I'll look into it!